# ada 95 Put (Item : in String) vs Put (String)

Tags: ada

in Ada 95
is there any difference between Put (Item : in String) and  Put (String)? or they are exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is part of a declaration, the other looks like a badly formed call (with a type name where a variable name should be)

On the other hand, there is no difference between

`Put (Item => MyString)`

and

```
Put (MyString)
```

except that the former uses "named association" and the latter uses "positional association".

In this simple example, named association has no real advantage, but it can avoid serious mistakes when there are more parameters.

Spot the difference between these, for example:

```
Set_Autopilot(15000, -500);
```

and

```
Set_Autopilot(Climb_Rate => 15000, Altitude => -500);
```

Ouch!

Comment: +1 for your plane/sub and being 500 feet below the surface of the sea.
Or a big crater.

Comment: You might get away with it in Death Valley, for a while ... unless the autopilot raises a Constraint Error!